# How to generate a non square matrix m*n in python? Given length L and if L is not a perfect square m > n

Tags: python-3.x, performance, math, matrix, runtime

I am trying to generate a grid symmetric or asymmetric based on the given length L

when L is a perfect square
L = 4, m=n=2
L = 9, m=n=3

but if L is not a perfect square
L = 6, m=3,n=2
L = 7, m=4,n=2

I have the following code, if it helps others or if one could suggest improvements:

```
def get_rows_cols(self):
    sr = math.sqrt(len(self._data.columns))
    numberOfCols = math.floor(sr)
    numberOfRows = 0
    if ((sr - math.floor(sr)) == 0):
        numberOfRows = math.floor(sr)
    else:
        diff = (len(self._data.columns)-1) - pow(numberOfCols,2)
        numberOfRows = (diff / numberOfCols) + 1 + numberOfCols
    n = numberOfCols
    m = int(numberOfRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have determined your `numberOfCols` and `numberOfRows`. If all you want to do is make a grid, you could do it in a `pandas` dataframe (I'll let you look that one up), or go old-school and just have a list of lists:

```
rows = []
one_row = [0] * numberOfCols
for i in range(numberOfRows):
    rows.append(one_row)
```

This will give you a list of lists, where you can access a cell by using the row index and the col index: `row[desired_row][desired_col]`

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. Although my struggle was to get the number of rows and cols. Was looking for a smarter math for that.